# How to LINQ List<List<object>> and flatten it using SelectMany?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

```
class Player
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{   
    List<object> cricketPlayers = new List<object>();
    cricketPlayers.Add(new Player { ID = 1, Name = "Dhoni" });
    cricketPlayers.Add(new Player { ID = 2, Name = "Kohli" });
    cricketPlayers.Add(new Player { ID = 3, Name = "Gibbs" });
    cricketPlayers.Add(new Player { ID = 4, Name = "Ponting" });
    cricketPlayers.Add(new Player { ID = 5, Name = "Flintoff" });

    List<object> footBallPlayers = new List<object>();
    footBallPlayers.Add(new Player { ID = 6, Name = "Ronaldinho" });
    footBallPlayers.Add(new Player { ID = 7, Name = "Messi" });
    footBallPlayers.Add(new Player { ID = 8, Name = "Ronaldo" });

    List<object> tennisPlayers = new List<object>();
    tennisPlayers.Add(new Player { ID = 9, Name = "Federer" });
    tennisPlayers.Add(new Player { ID = 10, Name = "Nadal" });

    List<object> players = new List<object>();
    players.Add(cricketPlayers);
    players.Add(footBallPlayers);
    players.Add(tennisPlayers);

    players.Dump();
}
```

[Please click here to view the Result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTncB.png)

I executed the above C# program in LINQPad and got the result given in the image.  I need to write a Lambda Expression LINQ to get only the ten player objects (SelectMany???). Please let me know how to do this through LINQ (not using loop).

PS:

I get the 'players' list from an API. I am unable to change the API to return the players list in a different way.

Comment: Start by changing `List<object>` to `List<Player>` and then try again.

Comment: Yes, select many

Comment: Also, what are you trying to achieve. Could could add `type` to the player class and then have a single list

Comment: `players.Take(10)` ??

Comment: //Also, what are you trying to achieve. Could could add type to the player class and then have a single list//

Yes, I want to get a List<Player> and it should contain all those 10 player objects

Comment: Make `players` a `List<Player>` and use 'AddRange'

Comment: "through LINQ (not using loop)." What do you think linq does? It uses loops anyway, so you don´t gain *anything* by prefering LINQ over a loop-based approach. Instead you´re only *hiding* complexity, which is a bad idea.

Comment: //Start by changing List<object> to List<Player> and then try again.//

The code I posted is just an example. The actual code is in a different program and I could not change List<object> to List<Player>

Comment: You can do this, but use stringtypes please: `players.Select(h => ((IList)h).Cast<Player>()).SelectMany(item => item).Dump();`

Comment: @MAK Can you confirm this is the actual question you are asking: You have a `List<object>` that actually contains `List<List<Player>>` and you want to get a list of players in one big list?

Comment: //@MAK Can you confirm this is the actual question you are asking: You have a List<object> that actually contains List<List<Player>> and you want to get a list of players in one big list?//

Exactly!

Comment: This sounds a lot like an XY Problem:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @MAK Very well, then see my answer.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please see the 'edit'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a `List<object>` that actually contains `List<List<Player>>` and you want to get a list of players in one big list. Unfortunately for some external reason you are unable to change the API to give you sensibly typed data, you need to go through a couple of hoops. So given this:

```
List<object> players = <snip>;
```

You can extract a list of `Player` objects using `SelectMany` with some casting:

```
var allPlayers = players
    .SelectMany(list => (List<object>)list)
    .Cast<Player>();
```

Answer (score 2):

If that's all information you need, then you just have to select the lists each by itself to concat them to a flatten list.

```
players.SelectMany(list => list);
```

I would recommmend to group them (with `.GroupBy()`) or give them some more information, because when you flatten the list you lose the information which player is playing what sport - this information is currently only part of the list.

Comment: Close, but see my answer for a complete reason why this code won't work without some tweaks.

Comment: you are completely right, there's no way to use SelectMany on `object`, which I overlooked without a compiler :) your answer deserves an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
List<Players> players = new List<Players>();
players.AddRange(cricketPlayers);
players.AddRange(footBallPlayers);
players.AddRange(tennisPlayers);
```

Then they will all be in the same list

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want all of the player objects in a single list, you could do something like this:

```
var players = cricketPlayers.Concat(footBallPlayers).Concat(tennisPlayers);
```

Your lists should probably also be of type `Player`, not `object`.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this be a better approach?

```
enum Sport
{
    Cricket,
    Fooball,
    Tennis
}

class Player
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Sport Sport { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    List<Player> players = new List<Player>();

    players.Add(new Player { ID = 1, Name = "Dhoni", Sport = Sport.Cricket });
    players.Add(new Player { ID = 2, Name = "Kohli", Sport = Sport.Cricket });
    players.Add(new Player { ID = 3, Name = "Gibbs", Sport = Sport.Cricket });
    players.Add(new Player { ID = 4, Name = "Ponting", Sport = Sport.Cricket });
    players.Add(new Player { ID = 5, Name = "Flintoff", Sport = Sport.Cricket });

    players.Add(new Player { ID = 6, Name = "Ronaldinho", Sport = Sport.Fooball });
    players.Add(new Player { ID = 7, Name = "Messi", Sport = Sport.Fooball });
    players.Add(new Player { ID = 8, Name = "Ronaldo", Sport = Sport.Fooball });

    players.Add(new Player { ID = 9, Name = "Federer", Sport = Sport.Tennis });
    players.Add(new Player { ID = 10, Name = "Nadal", Sport = Sport.Tennis });

    players.Select(p => p.Name).Dump();
    players.Where(p => p.Sport == Sport.Fooball).Select(p => p.Name).Dump();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the below section of code,

```
players.Add(cricketPlayers);
players.Add(footBallPlayers);
players.Add(tennisPlayers);
```

to this,

```
players.AddRange(cricketPlayers);
players.AddRange(footBallPlayers);
players.AddRange(tennisPlayers);
```

Comment: It actually worked. But I don't have control over how the players list is created. So, I can't change it to AddRange. Suppose the 'players' remains a List<object>, how to flatten it using linq?

Comment: @MAK you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50968975/edit) that condition into your question. Nowhere do you mention that you are restricted of using AddRange instead of Add.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, change definition of player list:

`List<List<object>> players = new List<List<object>>();`

And use `players.SelectMany(x=>x).ToList().Dump();`

```
class Player
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{   
    List<object> cricketPlayers = new List<object>();
    cricketPlayers.Add(new Player { ID = 1, Name = "Dhoni" });
    cricketPlayers.Add(new Player { ID = 2, Name = "Kohli" });
    cricketPlayers.Add(new Player { ID = 3, Name = "Gibbs" });
    cricketPlayers.Add(new Player { ID = 4, Name = "Ponting" });
    cricketPlayers.Add(new Player { ID = 5, Name = "Flintoff" });

    List<object> footBallPlayers = new List<object>();
    footBallPlayers.Add(new Player { ID = 6, Name = "Ronaldinho" });
    footBallPlayers.Add(new Player { ID = 7, Name = "Messi" });
    footBallPlayers.Add(new Player { ID = 8, Name = "Ronaldo" });

    List<object> tennisPlayers = new List<object>();
    tennisPlayers.Add(new Player { ID = 9, Name = "Federer" });
    tennisPlayers.Add(new Player { ID = 10, Name = "Nadal" });

    List<List<object>> players = new List<List<object>>();
    players.Add(cricketPlayers);
    players.Add(footBallPlayers);
    players.Add(tennisPlayers);

    players.SelectMany(x=>x).ToList().Dump();
}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is, that `Add` won´t add the elements of the sub-list to `players`, but just the `cricktePlayer`-instance itself. A `List<Player>` is also an `object`. So the following will of course just add three list-objects into your list of `object`.

```
List<object> players = new List<object>();
players.Add(cricketPlayers);
players.Add(footBallPlayers);
players.Add(tennisPlayers);
```

If you would print those lis, e.g. by the following:

```
foreach(var l in players)
    Console.WriteLine(l);
```

you would get something like the following:

> ```
> System.Collections.Generic.List'1'.
> System.Collections.Generic.List'1'.
> System.Collections.Generic.List'1'.
> ```

That shows that you don´t put the elements of your sub-list into your `players`-list, but the sublists themselves. In other words you dn´t have a `List<Player>`, but a `List<List<Player>>`. So every element in `players` itself is a `List<Player>`, not a `Player`.

That´s why others suggested to make `players` a `List<Player>` and then to use `AddRange`.

However as this doesn´t seem possible for whatever reason, you have to loop every element from your sublist and add the current element to your `player`-list:

```
foreach(var p in cricktePlayers)
    players.Add(p);
```

**In fact that´s the exact same a linq-based appraoch will do anyway, it only hides those loops from you.**

Fortunalety there´s a more convenient way to do this by using `AddRange`:

```
players.AddRange(cricketPlayers.Cast<Player>());
```

This is not even LINQ, however it also loops your `cricketPlayers`-list. So in fact there´s no way to magically bypass looping the lists. All you can do is to save some lines of code.